# How can I delete commits that are after the current HEAD?

Tags: git, git-commit

In my Git repository, I created three commits in a row: `commit1`, `commit2`, and `commit3`.

I then realized I messed up in `commit2` and `commit3`, and decided to go back to `commit1`. To do that, I ran

```
git checkout commit1
```

Now I am in `commit1`. How do I delete `commit2` and `commit3`?

Comment: Note, after doing `checkout commit1` (where `commit1` is a commit ID, remote branch or tag) you're on a _detached head_ (=not on a branch). You'll then have to checkout your branch and follow the `reset` steps described in comment and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Check your branch out and then reset it

Based on your description and under the assumption you were on some branch called `mybranch` before checking out `commit1` (`C1` in my graphs below), you must be in the following situation:

```
C1 [HEAD]
 \
  C2 -- C3 [mybranch]
```

Commits `C2` and `C3` still appear in the output of `git log` because they're still reachable from the `mybranch` refererence. Also, note that `HEAD` is detached. What you should do is...

1. Reattach `HEAD` to `mybranch`, by running

   ```sh
   git checkout mybranch
   ```

   This should put you in the following situation:

   ```
   C1
    \
     C2 -- C3 [HEAD -> mybranch]
   ```
2. Reset the `mybranch` branch to its tip's grandparent, by running

   ```sh
   git reset --hard mybranch~2
   ```

   That should put you in the following situation:

   ```
   C1 [HEAD -> mybranch]
   ```

Because commits `C2` and `C3` have now become unreachable (i.e. "deleted"), they're not shown on this last graph.

---

### Why resetting without first reattaching the HEAD won't work

This may be a bit cheeky, but here is an explanation of why the other two answers won't work. As correctly pointed out by cmbuckley in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646646/how-can-i-delete-commits-that-are-after-the-current-head/27646740#comment43712010_27646673),

> `git reset` resets the state of the current branch you’re on (so you’d need to be on the branch to do that). If you’ve checked out `commit1`, you’re probably not on a branch (detached HEAD state).

Since the OP (Imray) is in detached HEAD state, running git-reset *before* reattaching HEAD to the branch will *not* move the branch reference in question. Here is a toy example illustrating this.

```sh
# set things up
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/jubobs/Desktop/test/.git/

# create a first commit
$ touch README
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "add README"
[master (root-commit) 85137ba] add README
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README

# create a second commit
$ printf "foo\n" > README
$ git commit -am "write 'foo' in README"
[master 3948e84] write 'foo' in README
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

# inspect the log
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
* 3948e84 (HEAD, master) write 'foo' in README
* 85137ba add README

# check out the second commit (which detaches the HEAD)
$ git checkout 3948e84
Note: checking out '3948e84'.
# (boilerplate stdout is omitted...)
HEAD is now at 3948e84... write 'foo' in README

# reset to the first commit (equivalent to 'git reset --hard 85137ba')
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
HEAD is now at 85137ba add README
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
* 3948e84 (master) write 'foo' in README
* 85137ba (HEAD) add README
```

Note that the `git reset` command moved `HEAD` to the initial commit, but did *not* move the `master` branch whatsoever. The second commit is not "deleted", because it's still *reachable* from `master`; it is therefore listed in the output of `git log`.

Comment: I wasn't on my `master` branch, I'm on a different branch

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're in the master branch in your repo for naming purposes, but any branch will do. This can be thought of as simply a pointer to a commit object. You can also think of HEAD as another pointer, which you can move around with `git checkout`

```
commit1  ->  commit2  ->  commit3
                             ^
                             |
                           master
```

If you want to change your master pointer to be at commit1, then you need to issue a `git reset` command, as others have indicated.

```
git reset --hard commit1
```

This moves the master pointer in the above diagram to same place as the commit1 object.

Note, you aren't actually deleting the commit2 and commit3 objects, it's just that within git there's no branches pointing to them, so git is free to clean them up if it wants to, or you can force it by running a garbage collect with something like:

```
git gc --aggressive --prune
```

Until it is actively cleared from your repo, you can still checkout both commit2 and commit3, so despite you moving the master pointer back to commit1 (with `git reset`), you have to be careful if (say) you accidentally commit passwords to the repository and are trying to revert back - they will still be in your local repo until pruned.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm not in my `master` branch, but rather `myFirstBranch`?

Comment: no, i only said master so the rest of the text was relevant to that branch. all branches are just names of pointers.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Because the OP is in detached HEAD state, `git reset --hard commit1` will *not* move `master`.

Comment: Calling `gc` will not get rid of the commits because they are still referenced by the reflog of `HEAD` and the branch that committed it. Unreferenced commits are only removed from the reflog after 30 days by default.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss `git gc` with the appropriate flags will.

Comment: @Jubobs Can you inform everybody what they are?

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss Sorry, I read your comment a bit too quickly. Yes, `git gc` alone is not enough to get rid of objects that are reachable from the reflog.

Answer (score 1):

### Force Your Branch to Current HEAD and Checkout Branch

```
git branch -f mybranch
git checkout -
```

### Checkout Branch and Force Your Branch to Current HEAD

```
git checkout -
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

The second option is particular advantageous because you do not need to type the name of your branh or the identity of your current commit. You could even make it an alias.

**EDIT:** This assumes that you have not been jumping around, and your most recent checkout was from your branch.

Comment: Careful: `git checkout -` assumes that the OP hasn't been jumping around the commit graph.

Comment: @Jubobs You are right. I did not realize that. However, it is still useful when you first checkout instead of resetting (which can happen to the best of us).

Answer (score 0):

You want to nuke commit `commit3` (Assuming you are currently on commit3 - as `HEAD`). you can do following:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

The result is:

```
commit1 -> commit2 
              ↑
             HEAD
```

You can follow similar process for moving back to `commit1` (i.e. `git reset --hard HEAD~2`).

Comment: Assuming `commit1` is the hash of the commit, you can also just do `git reset --hard commit1`. If the branch exists on the remote as it did locally, you’ll also need to `git push --force`.

Comment: @cmbuckley Are you still assuming I'm on `commit3` (as answerer does) or do I do that while I'm on `commit1`?

Comment: `git reset` resets the state of the current branch you’re on (so you’d need to be on the branch to do that). If you’ve checked out `commit1`, you’re probably not on a branch (detached HEAD state).

Comment: The OP wrote: *I [...] decided to go back to `commit1`.* That's not what your answer does.