# What does a message starting with D mean when doing a Git checkout?

Tags: git, message, git-checkout

When I checkout checkout the branch I'm currently working on (after switching back to `master` for a moment), I get this message.

```
C:\wamp\www\budgeteer\v4>git checkout various
D       static/src/app/project/collaborators/collaborators.html
D       static/src/app/project/collaborators/collaborators.js
Switched to branch 'various'
```

Can someone explain what it means? I can't find something similar in the Git docs.

Comment: D stands for deleted if I'm not mistaken. Which means on branch `various`, those files does not exist compared to the preivous one.

Comment: Please review [the answers you got to your other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1675976%20hasaccepted%3ano), including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646646/how-can-i-delete-commits-that-are-after-the-current-head).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`D` means files were deleted, other cases may be - added `A`, modified `M`